# Nginx - Reverse Proxy - UDP

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add a UDP port forwarding to nginx and I have following entry in nginx.conf:

```
stream {
    upstream test_udp {
        server localhost:5151; 
       }

  server {
        listen     5151 udp;
        proxy_pass test_udp;
      }
 }
```

When I try to start the nginx, I get following error:

nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5151 failed (13: Permission denied)

Thoughts, comments or guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how are you trying to restart nginx?

Comment: sudo systemctl nginx restart